# How to calculate the eigenvector of a column stochastic matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have a column stochastic matrix A and want to solve the following equation in C++: 
Ax=x

I am assuming that I need to find out an eigenvector x where eigenvalue is set to be 1(right?) but I couldn't figure it out in C++. So far I have checked out some math-libs such as Seldon, CPPScaLapack, Eigen... Among them, Eigen seems a good option but I couldn't understand how to utilize any of them to solve the equation above.

Can you give me some suggestions/code snippets or ideas to solve the equation?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

edit: A is n-by-n real, non-negative matrix.

Comment: Are you trying to solve it in the general case for any sized matrix A?

Comment: What dimensions can A be? Are complex eigenvalues allowed?

Comment: The eigenvalue would have to be 1 in this case.

Comment: Duh... I started thinking about the general solution. In that case, it's probably simpler to find the null space of A-I, since (A-I)x=x is a homogeneous system. Are the entries of A complex?

Comment: This might be a good one to put to math.stackexchange.com . The hard part here is figuring out the algorithm; once you've got the math, typing it into C++ source is easy.

Comment: The algorithm to solve homogeneous systems is fairly straightforward: use [Gauss-Jordan reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Jordan_reduction) to compute the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29). The question is, what C++ math libraries support it?

Comment: A is an n-by-n square matrix which is strictly real, non negative(>0). @zipcodeman right eigenvalue = 1 in this case. I need to solve (A-I)x=0 I checkout out Seldon it has direct/iterative solver support but I couldn't get it work in my case :s

Comment: Too bad you aren't using something like R or MATLAB where it would be trivial

Comment: trivial... but very slow in general and with poor interoperability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind I've not used Eigen, but its [`EigenSolver`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html) and [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html) look to be able to solve this. These are listed as "experimental", so there might be bugs and the API might change in the future.

```
// simple, not very efficient
template <typename _M> 
bool isSelfAdjoint(const _M& a) {
    return a == a.adjoint();
}

template <typename _M> 
std::pair<Eigen::EigenSolver<_M>::EigenvalueType Eigen::EigenSolver<_M>::EigenvectorType>
eigenvectors(const _M& a) {
    if (isSelfAdjoint(a)) {
        Eigen::EigenSolver<M> saes(a);
        return pair(saes.eigenvalues(), saes.eigenvectors());
    } else {
        Eigen::EigenSolver<M> es(a);
        return pair(es.eigenvalues, es.eigenvectors());
    }
}
```

The two solver classes have different types for the eigen value and eigen vector collections, but as they're both based on class Matrix and Matrices are convertible, the above it should work.

Alternatively, you could approach the problem as the [homogeneous linear equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems) (A-I<sub>n</sub>) **x** = **0**, which can be solved by converting A-I<sub>n</sub> to an upper triangular matrix. [Gaussian elimination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html) will do that (though you'll need to skip the normalizing step for each row where you ensure the leading coefficient is 1, as integers aren't a field). A quick perusal of the above projects didn't turn up support for row echelon conversion, which probably means I missed it. In any case, it's not too hard to implement with a few helper classes (`RowMajor`, `RowMajor::iterator`, `RowWithPivot` in the following). I haven't even tested whether or not this will compile, so take it as more of an illustration of the algorithm than a complete, drop-in solution. Though the sample uses functions, it might make more sense to use a class (à la EigenSolver).

```
/* Finds a row with the lowest pivot index in a range of matrix rows.
 * Arguments:
 * - start: the first row to check 
 * - end:   row that ends search range (not included in search)
 * - pivot_i (optional): if a row with pivot index == pivot_i is found, search 
 *     no more. Can speed things up if the pivot index of all rows in the range
 *     have a known lower bound.
 *
 * Returns an iterator p where p->pivot_i = min([start .. end-1]->pivot_i)
 *
 */
template <typename _M>
RowMajor<_M>::iterator 
find_lead_pivot (RowMajor<_M>::iterator start,
                 const RowMajor<_M>::iterator& end,
                 int pivot_i=0) 
{
    RowMajor<_M>::iterator lead=start;
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
        if (start->pivot() <= pivot_i) {
            return start;
        }
        if (start->pivot() < lead->pivot()) {
            lead = start;
        }
    }
    return end;
}

/* Returns a matrix that's the row echelon form of the passed in matrix.
 */
template <typename _M>
_M form_of_echelon(const _M& a) {
    _M a_1 = a-_M::Identity();
    RowMajor<_M> rma_1 = RowMajor<_M>(a_1);
    typedef RowMajor<_M>::iterator RMIter;
    RMIter lead;
    int i=0;

    /*
      Loop invariant: row(i).pivot_i <= row(j).pivot_i, for j st. j>i
     */
    for (RMIter row_i = rma_1.begin(); 
         row_i != rma_1.end() && row_i->pivot() != 0; 
         ++row_i, ++i) 
    {
        lead = find_lead_pivot(row_i, rma_1.end(), i);
        // ensure row(i) has minimal pivot index
        swap(*lead, *row_i);

        // ensure row(j).pivot_i > row(i).pivot_i
        for (RMIter row_j = row_i+1; 
             row_j != rma_1.end(); 
             ++row_j) 
        {
            *row_j = *row_j * row_i->pivot() - *row_i * row_j->pivot();
        }
        /* the best we can do towards true row echelon form is reduce 
         * the leading coefficient by the row's GCD
         */
        // *row_i /= gcd(*row_i);
    }
    return static_cast<_M>(rma_1);
}

/* Converts a matrix to echelon form in-place
 */
template <typename _M>
_M& form_of_echelon(_M& a) {
    a -= _M::Identity();
    RowMajor<_M> rma_1 = RowMajor<_M>(a);
    typedef RowMajor<_M>::iterator RMIter;
    RMIter lead;
    int i=0;

    /*
      Loop invariant: row(i).pivot_i <= row(j).pivot_i, for j st. j>i
     */
    for (RMIter row_i = rma_1.begin(); 
         row_i != rma_1.end() && row_i->pivot() != 0; 
         ++row_i, ++i) 
    {
        lead = find_lead_pivot(row_i, rma_1.end(), i);
        // ensure row(i) has minimal pivot index
        swap(*lead, *row_i);

        for (RMIter row_j = row_i+1; 
             row_j != rma_1.end(); 
             ++row_j) 
        {
            *row_j = *row_j * row_i->pivot() - *row_i * row_j->pivot();
        }
        /* the best we can do towards true row echelon form is reduce 
         * the leading coefficient by the row's GCD
         */
        // *row_i /= gcd(*row_i);
    }
    return a;
}
```

The interfaces for the helper classes, which haven't been vetted for const-correctness and other necessary details that make C++ work.

```
template <typename _M>
class RowWithPivot {
public:
    typedef _M::RowXpr Wrapped;
    typedef _M::Scalar Scalar;

    RowWithPivot(_M& matrix, size_t row);

    Wrapped base();
    operator Wrapped();

    void swap(RowWithPivot& other);

    int cmp(RowWithPivot& other) const;
    bool operator <(RowWithPivot& other) const;

    // returns the index of the first non-zero scalar
    // (best to cache this)
    int pivot_index() const;
    // returns first non-zero scalar, or 0 if none
    Scalar pivot() const;
};

template <typename _M, typename _R = RowWithPivot<_M> >
class RowMajor {
public:
    typedef _R value_type;

    RowMajor(_M& matrix);

    operator _M&();
    _M& base();

    value_type operator[](size_t i);

    class iterator {
    public:
        // standard random access iterator
        ...
    };

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
};
```

Comment: Outis thank you so much! I came across with this link: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=83060. I am using SuperLU  to solve the problem as efficiency is of paramount importance in my case ;)

Comment: No need; if you found a better solution, you can post it and accept it. I'd like to see what you wound up doing, if it's something else.